# SENDGRID email confirmation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, sendgrid, email-confirmation

Im trying to use email verification with SendGrid. The error that Im getting while trying to register using http://goo.gl/77WXpT this tutorial is :

Bad Request

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Bad Request

Source Error:

```
      if (transportWeb != null)
      {
           await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
```

and the source code of identityConfig.cs is:

```
 public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configSendGridasync(message);
    }
    // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                            "Joe@contoso.com", "Joe S.");
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your username/password for Sendgrid is not correct. Or the login you are using there does not have rights to send emails.

Comment: Change this Joe@contoso.com to yours

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with your credentials.

If you signed up with SendGrid through Windows Azure, then you need to do the following:

1. Log in to your `Azure Portal`
2. Navigate to the `Marketplace`
3. Locate and click on the `SendGrid` application
4. Down at the bottom, click on `Connection Info`
5. Use the `Username` and `Password` listed.

I was initially under the impression that I was to use my Azure account password until I found this.  Hope this corrects your problem like it did for me.